# Partial derivatives question help here?

Tags: derivatives

I have the function 
$$u=\frac{x^3+8xy^2-y^3}{x^3+y^3}.$$
I have to show if 
$$x\cdot \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) 
 +\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)=0.$$

How do I find du/dx and du/dy?

Answer (score 2):

You calculate
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{2 y^2 \left(-8 x^3+3 x^2 y+4 y^3\right)}{\left(x^3+y^3\right)^2}$$
by taking $y$ constant and just differentiate a function with one variable.

The partial derivative in respect to $x$ of the nominator is
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} (x^3+8xy^2-y^3)=3x^2 + 8y^2$$
and the partial derivative in respect to $x$ of the denominator is
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} (x^3+y^3)= 3 x^2$$